# progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); Is there anybody please tell where i can use Progressbar gone after stop loading

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

I'm new in Java Android Development & I was trying to develop something but I have to use the progress bar in WebView but I don't know How I have to use code stop progress bar after completed loading.

```
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

   mhelp = (LinearLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.lythelp);
                mhelp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Help.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not set the progressBar visibility after you start a new activity. The simplest thing you can do is use a flag variable to hold the state of your progress bar.

```
startActivity(intent);
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); // should be avoided
```

SOLUTION:

```
private ProgressBar progressBar;
String progressBarState = "empty"
String PROGRESS_BAR_LOADING = "LOADING"
String PROGRESS_BAR_LOADED = "LOADED"

mhelp = (LinearLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.lythelp);

mhelp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
if(PROGRESS_BAR_LOADING == "LOADING")
  progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Help.class);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

Inside HelpActivity (or whatever activity you want to start):

```
override onCreate(): void {
  /*
  * You will need a progress bar on this activity's view 
  * as well if you are transitioning between activities and
  * want to maintain the progress.
  */

  progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

  /*
  * You can pass the progress between the activities by
  * passing the completion rate through the bundle that is
  * sent through the activities.
  * You can also add a  key value pair for the progress bar's
  * current state in that bundle and check for that state in the
  * onCreate.
  */
}
```